# Can I send a binary variable using HTTP::Request::Common::post?

Tags: perl, http, gzip

I want to send data that I have compressed with gzip before with an post
request without saving it to a file.
In the documentation of HTTP::Request::Common I see nowhere explained how to just post the compressed data that I have made before.

```
I want to emulate this call,
curl -F "file0=@+Wowhead_Looter.lua.gz" -F "file1=@creaturecache.wdb.gz" -F "file2=@gameobjectcache.wdb.gz" \
     -F "file3=@itemcache.wdb.gz" -F "file4=@pagetextcache.wdb.gz" \
     -F "file5=@questcache.wdb.gz" "URL"
```

I dont know if this is exact one call or multiple calls.

Can somebody help me on this?

I have this function that reads all files and returns the object with all compressed files:

```
sub compress_wdb
{
   my ($wdb_dir,
       $wdb_dir_dh,
       @wdb_dir_files,
       $file,
       $vol,
       $dir,
       $ffile,
       %gzipped_wdb);

   $wdb_dir = shift;
   opendir $wdb_dir_dh, $wdb_dir,;
   @wdb_dir_files = grep(/^.+\..+$/, readdir $wdb_dir_dh);
   closedir $wdb_dir_dh;


   for $file (@wdb_dir_files)
   {
      gzip $wdb_dir."/".$file => \$gzipped_wdb{$file}
          or die "gzip failed: $GzipError\n";
   }

   return %gzipped_wdb;
}
```

the function later gets called like this:

```
my %wdb = compress_wdb($wdb_dir);
```

Then there's the post function, where I have the issue:

```
sub post
{
   my ($auth_user, $auth_password, $data, $ua, $req);

   $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

   $req = $ua->post("URL",
  Content_Type => 'form-data',
  Content => [
   #  $addon => [ $obj ],
  ],
);
}
```

Which is than called like this:

```
post(\%wdb);
```

Comment: Thats someone I know only didn't knowed how to send a document with the contens of a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Side note: Predeclaring variables, as in

```
   my ($wdb_dir,
       $wdb_dir_dh,
       @wdb_dir_files,
       $file,
       $vol,
       $dir,
       $ffile,
       %gzipped_wdb);
```

is considered bad style. A variable should be declared in the smallest scope possible, which usually means it should be declared when first used.

(Also, 3 space indentation is weird.)

---

According to [the `curl` manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F), `-F` specifies fields for a web form submission (specifically, in `multipart/form-data` format). A value prefixed with `@` makes curl upload a file (attached to the POST request).

The [`LWP::UserAgent` documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#post) says the `post` method calls `HTTP::Request::Common::POST` underneath.

The [`HTTP::Request::Common` documentation for `POST`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request::Common#POST-$url) says you can create a `multipart/form-data` request by specifying the content type as `'form-data'`. It also says you can do a file upload by specifying an array reference as the form field value, and you can create a "virtual file" by setting the `Content` pseudo-header (which bypasses reading an actual file from disk).

Putting it all together:

```
sub post
{
    my ($files) = @_;

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

    my $response = $ua->post(
        "YOUR URL HERE",
        Content_Type => 'form-data',
        Content => [
            do {
                my $i = 0;
                map +(
                    'file' . $i++ => [ undef, $_, Content => $files->{$_} ] 
                ),
                sort keys %$files
            }
        ],
    );

    ...
}
```

We iterate over the keys of `%$files`, which I assume are the short names of the compressed files. (We also do it in alphabetical order to make it deterministic, which is often nice for debugging.)

We also maintain a counter (`$i`), which we use for generating the form field names.

For each filename (stored in `$_` by `map`), we produce a key-value pair. The key is the form field name (consisting of `field` and the current counter value), the value is an array reference (this is our file upload spec).

The array reference contains a file of `undef` (because we don't want to read a real file from disk), an upload filename of `$_` (this is what we want the web server to see the filename as; maybe you want to pass `"$_.gz"` here?), and the most important part, the actual content stored under `$files->{$_}`.

All of this happens right in the call to `post` thanks to the `do` block, which is admittedly cheeky. You could equally well create the data structure beforehand:

```
my @fields;
for my $name (sort keys %$files) {
    push @fields, 'file' . @fields => [ undef, $name, Content => $files->{$name} ];
    # we don't need a counter here because we can just ask @fields how big it is
}
```

and then pass `Content => \@fields` in the `post` call.

Comment: Re "*Also, 3 space indentation is weird*", :p

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explenation.  The last one is the solution I used. The 3 spaces indentation is set from emacs and In just kept using it.